# Can numbers be rounded (math term) using LESS CSS?

Tags: less

LESS CSS = http://lesscss.org/

I declared a variable, like this... `@height: 30px`

Then I used a simple calculation, like this... `line-height: @height * .666`

It returns `19.98px` but I wanted an even `20px`

So, does LESS CSS have a way to round numbers up or down?

Comment: Well, jquery does and LESS is based on JjQuery.

Comment: @Greg LESS is a language that compiles to CSS. It has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: @Paulpro : From wikipedia:  LESS is open-source. Its first version was written in Ruby, however in the later versions, use of Ruby has been deprecated and replaced by JavaScript.

Comment: @Greg Yeah, the official compiler is written in Javascript. There is also a popular compiler written in PHP. It still has nothing to do with jQuery and even the Javascript compiler doesn't use jQuery. `LESS` itself is a language. Just like `Javascript`, `CSS`, `C++`, and `HTML` are all languages.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes they can:

```
line-height: ceil(@height * .666);      // 20px (round up)
line-height: floor(@height * .666);    // 19px (round down)
line-height: round(@height * .666);     // 20px (round to closest integer)
line-height: round(@height * .666, 1);  // 20.0px (round to 1 decimal place)
```

Comment: Thanks @Paulpro I'll accept this answer as soon as it allows.  Do you have any resources (aka: links) you can recommend for other LESS "tricks"?  I'm new to LESS and I didn't see much on the official site.

Comment: @Kirkland You can always just scan [the reference (link)](http://lesscss.org/#reference) for a function that suits your needs:

Comment: @Paulpro: Math.ceil(number) is a javscript function.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/w0w5b52h%28v=vs.94%29.aspx as are the others.

Comment: @Greg ceil is also in `C`, `C#`, `C++`, `PHP`, and a whole bunch of other languages, including `LESS`.

Comment: @Greg You may also notice that the `round` function in Javascript doesn't take in a second argument to specify the number of decimal places, like the `round` in LESS does.

Comment: is it possible without preprocessors like LESS? so just CSS...?

Answer (score 2):

http://lesscss.org/functions/ for a list of the lesscss functions, floor is included under the heading "Math functions".