# CSS how to round of percent values to whole number pixel

Tags: html, css

In CSS, when width, height, margin etc use percentages, the result will sometimes come back with a fractional pixel length, e.g. 100.25px. I want to know how to round off this to the next integer. This seems to be quite a common issue; I've searched around it a lot, but have yet to find a solution.

For example, in the code below, Chrome rounds 50.6px to 50px, which isn't the mathematical standard.

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f9e7d0), color-stop(72%,#f9e7d0), color-stop(72%,#207cca), color-stop(72%,#b08b5b), color-stop(100%,#b08b5b));
```

In JavaScript this would be achievable using the ceil function, but can it be done in pure CSS?

Comment: what do you mean by "doing in css"? You can try to use some css framework like sass or less.

Comment: i want result of percent should be round of to next integer value. like 100.25px to 101px

Comment: yeah, but why in css...?

Comment: like @Krab said, you can do something like that in less or sass. but i dont think it's what you want.  here's an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495302/can-numbers-be-rounded-math-term-using-less-css

Comment: between divs gap is visible and many look wise issues

Comment: same question is asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308989/are-the-decimal-places-in-a-css-width-respected

Comment: @OP: You've got a pretty well-hidden case of [the XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Browsers round fractional pixels automatically - some up, some down; this is hard coded into the browsers so there's no way to force it to do one or the other with CSS.

A more indepth look at how different browsers treat fractional pixels can be found [here](http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/browsers-and-fractional-pixels/).

Comment: AFAIK not quite right (anymore). Chrome (proably WebKit/Blink in general) seems to work with sub-pixels for quite some time.

Comment: Yeah. This answer is dated now but was right at the time.