# CSS: different width and height in pixels with same value in em

Tags: css, screen-resolution

In CSS, I have a `1em` square div:

```
.mydiv {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}
```

but since `1em = 15.4375px` and height resolution must be different than width resolution, the square doesn't look really square but rectangular.

[image]

Anyone experienced this?
Is there a way I can fix this? Maybe a CSS function that would round `em` in `px`?

Comment: pixel on a monitor aren't necessarily square https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin-film-transistor_liquid-crystal_display#/media/File:Dell_axim_LCD_under_microscope.jpg

Comment: The appearance of an element on the screen depends on many things, not just `width` and `height`. You also have `box-sizing`, `padding`, `margin`, `border`, `display`, `min-width`, `max-width` etc! So can you show a more complete example that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: As to your actual question, the answer is no. You'll have to use JavaScript to round. Or, according to the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17495302/1016716), LESS can do it too.